# Content scripts being executed multiple times in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Currently, we have a content script which is initialised in the manifest.json file as follows:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
    "matches": [
        "https://docs.google.com/*"
        ],
    "js ["content.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "all_frames": true, 
    "match_about_blank": true      
    }

],
```

which is set to run every time the user loads up a google docs document. However, by looking at the console logs it seems as if the content script is loaded (is the correct word injected?) into the new tab multiple times, as we get multiple console logs.

I've read in some other answers that this may have to do with the fact that the content script is loaded once when the google docs tab is loading, and once when it has finished loading, so it runs multiple times; though how do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 15):

The problem is `"all_frames": true`. Google Docs embeds many `iframe`s from the same domain:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/preload" style="display:none;" tabindex="-1"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/offline/iframeapi?ouid=REDACTED#cd=1" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Your content script is getting injected into all of these frames.

If you set `"all_frames": false`: your content will only get injected in to the top frame, and will log just once upon browsing to a Google Docs document.

Comment: Ok thanks for that! So what if we were trying to monitor the user's usage of google docs and needed our content script to be injected into all of the iframes, but we dont want our content script to be run several times? Is that possible?

Comment: These seem like fundamentally opposing goals. You've a constraint that you need the content script to be injected into all of the frames. This implies that it will run in all of them; that's unavoidable. It sounds like what you're trying to do is "using information from a variety of frames, run some script exactly once, then mutate (some of?) those frames". For this you need a way for the content scripts to orchestrate and talk to each other. You need a single shared state. You can use a "background script" for this; content scripts can send it messages, and it can send messages back.

Comment: Wow! really thank you. I spent all the day to find a solution and now we're in night. but your solution was the only one worked!